# @Html.ValidationFor() an @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, typeof(string).FullName)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a rickety old MVC client as part of my VS Solution, we'll call it ApiClient (a backend client). The Root Model, we'll call it User, has all the Validation requirements and messages. But, have a look at the code in the related View...

**View**

```
@using Cms.Utils
@using Utils.Strings
@using Utils.Web
@using Utils.DateTimes
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using Models
@model Cms.Models.Users.AddModel

@SectionBreadcrumb.Add(Html, "Manage Users", "Add")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>
            Add Person
        </h2>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                @*@Html.LabelFor(x => x.User.Username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.Username, typeof(string).FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.User.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**View's Model**

```
namespace Cms.Models.Users
{
    public class AddModel
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Here I must mention that User is a model in a Submodule (another project) in the solution. It also inherits from CoreUser (also in the same Submodule)*

**User Model**

```
namespace Models
{
    public class User : CoreUser
    {
        public bool IsFollowing { get; set; }
        public bool IsFollowingMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CoreUser Model**

```
namespace Sqor.Models
{
    public class CoreUser : IEntity, IAttributeContainer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256), RegularExpression(@"[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool IsPhoneVerified { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Usernames cannot exceed 20 characters."), RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z](_[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])+$", ErrorMessage = "Letters, numbers, and underscores only. Start with a letter. No spaces. Max length of 20 characters.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Snippet cannot exceed 200 characters.")]
        public string Snippet { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public bool IsTeam { get; set; }
        public bool IsAmbassador { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
        public int? ContractTypeId { get; set; }
        public bool IsMvp { get; set; }
        public string FacebookPageId { get; set; }
        public string TwitterHandle { get; set; }
        public string WikipediaUrl { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPosts { get; set; }
        public string College { get; set; }
        public bool? AdFree { get; set; }
        public bool MarketingEmails { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "First names cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        [Obsolete("Use FirstName property instead.")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Last names cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        [Obsolete("Use LastName property instead.")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this property moving forward.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "First names cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        public string FirstName
        {
#pragma warning disable 618
            get { return this.Firstname; }
            set { this.Firstname = value; }
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Use this property moving forward.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Last names cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        public string LastName
        {
#pragma warning disable 618
            get { return this.Lastname; }
            set { this.Lastname = value; }
#pragma warning restore 618
        }

        [RegularExpression(@"^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Please use a valid date. MM/DD/YYYY")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Locations cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Gender cannot exceed 45 characters.")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
        public string ProfileHeader { get; set; }
        public bool IsPlayer { get; set; }
        public bool IsUser { get; set; }

        public List<PlayerLeague> Leagues { get; set; }

        public List<AthleteContract> Contracts { get; set; }

        public List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

        public int? AccountManagerId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        }

        EntityType IEntity.Type
        {
            get { return EntityType.User; }
        }

        string IEntity.Name
        {
            get { return FullName; }
        }

        string IEntity.Team
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        string IEntity.League
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        int IEntity.LeaguePrecedence
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        string IEntity.JerseyNumber
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        string IEntity.Position
        {
            get { return null; }
        }


        [JsonIgnore]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes
        {
            get { return AttributeTokens != null ? AttributeTokens.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value == null ? null : x.Value.ToObject<object>()) : new Dictionary<string, object>(); }
            set { AttributeTokens = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value == null ? null : JToken.FromObject(x.Value)); }
        }

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, JToken> AttributeTokens { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public IEnumerable<AttributeValue> AttributeValues
        {
            get { return Attributes.Select(x => new AttributeValue { Name = x.Key, Value = x.Value }); }
            set { Attributes = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FullName + " (" + Id + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that in my View above each of the below...
@Html.EditorFor(x.User.Username) has an overload, typeof(string).FullName.
*@Html.EditorFor(x.User.Username, typeof(string).FullName, new { placeholder = "blah" })*

Essentially changing the name of my editor, therefore each client side @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x.User.Username) code does not activate.

Also, if I remove typeof(string).FullName from the @Html.EditorFor instances, my Client Side validation starts working, however when saving, it then passes null values to the related controller, so a User with all blank information gets created.

1. Why has the previous developer used this typeof(string).FullName thing and what exactly is it?
2. How can I rid myself of this typeof(string).FullName and it work with my model (ie. not send null values when submitted to the controller.) so that client side validation works?
3. Can I make client side validation work with the typeof(string).FullName thing in tact?

Thank you so much for any and all help!!

Solution Explorer [Solution Explorer Screenclip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9KQu.png)
@42shadow42 [Views/Shared/EditorTemplates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8TxN.png)

**UPDATE - UsersController.cs**

```
[Route("person/add"), HttpPost]
public new async Task<ActionResult> Add(string email,  string username, string firstName, string lastName, string snippet, string bio, bool isAmbassador = false, bool isTeam = false, Gender gender = Gender.None, string location = null, DateTime? birthdate = null, 
    string twitterHandle = null, string facebookPageId = null, string wikipediaUrl = null, bool marketingEmails = false, string[] roles = null)
```

Comment: I think it is the username(model) typeof...(template type), (i.e., system.string)

Comment: Can you provide us with the model?

Comment: done and what do you mean @nocturns2 ?

Comment: try putting `[Required]` overtop of `UserName` in `CoreUser` model

Comment: i have taken care of the Username and its error using the RegularExpression. It is not a required field.

Comment: Is there a folder called editor templates in the views/shared directory by chance?

Comment: Yep @42shadow42 there is. I have updated with a screenclip of this folder. Will also add any files you might want to see, thank you!

Comment: @haltandcode The typeof(string).FullName activiates the System.String.cshtml, which is incompatible with your validation system. You will need to update it.

Comment: thanks @42shadow42 trying

Comment: tried the above @42shadow42 in system.string.cshtml  what did i do wrong?

Comment: @nocturns2 you mentioned system.string as well. i do have a system.string.cshtml extensions file. how should I fix it to work with what I have? i have posted the updated Code above.

Comment: Can you provide the method signature of your controller action? (I.E. public ActionResult MyMethod(int prop1, int prop2)?

Answer (score 0):

1. The typeof(string).FullName directs MVC to use the editor template called System.String.cshtml
2. Possibly, see below.
3. Yes, see below depending on 2 this may or may not fix your model binding.

### Solution for 3

Try using this for your System.String.cshtml, if I'm correct it should render the same html styles and format, with built in support for the validation attributes you are using.

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model , new { @class = "col-xs-2" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model , new { @class = "col-xs-10" })
</div>
```

### Solution #1 for 2

If it doesn't model bind at this point you may need to change part of your main view:

Replace:

```
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.Username, typeof(string).FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.User.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

With

```
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.Username, typeof(string).FullName, "Username", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.User.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

### Solution #2 for 2

Alternatively you may be able to just update your controllers action method signature to use the parameter name "User". Like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(User User){
}
```

Comment: thanks man, 

Solution for #3 - did get client side validation work, but then the typeof(string).FullName editors sent null info (ill try a combo of it and without typeof(string).FullName)

Solution #1 for 2 - does send values through, but validation does not work. if i combine Solution for #3 with it the value is sent through, but validation does not work.

Solution #2 for 2 - Let me post my Controller

THANK U!

Comment: The Route I posted above is simply for calling an await to backend.CreatePerson(new PutPersonRequest) Hm. Maybe Solution #1 for 2 validation will work if i put it the requirements there. I'll post back soon.

Comment: Ok, i've tried all solutions except for #2 unsuccessfully, tried combinations of each solution, different results with each combination, either validation works and no data is sent, or validation doesnt work and the data is sent

Comment: Ok, through a combination of all of this I've got it working so I'm going to mark your answer and post the updated combination! THANK YOU SO MUCH